# Python loop(for specifically)

Tags: python

So I'm a complete newbie to Python, however, I'm familiar with C++.So when I tried to create the for loop in python I thought it followed the C++ pattern as in the for loop uses a variable in python and increments its value step by step.
Example:

```
for i in list:
    print (list[i])
```

This above would print list elements sequentially like list[0] first and list[1] second and so on.However, on analysis, I found it isn't so and Python actually takes values from the list and uses it and then goes to the next value.So my question is,is there a loop in Python that works like the for loop in C++? Thanks in advance.
**For loop in C++ :

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    cout << list[i] << endl;
}
```

This would print the elements in the list sequentially like list[0]-first list[1], list[2].If I were to print out I inside the loop it would print out 0,1,2(i<3).I hope I was able to explain the difference properly.

Comment: `for i in list:  print(i)` (if you don't care about the indices themselves)

Comment: note: your c++ loop is _wrong_.

Comment: Use `for i in range(len(list)): print(list[i])`

Comment: @JkShaw Don't use `for i in range(len(list)): print(list[i])`.

Comment: @bereal, i know it's not pythonic, just pointing out the way to do.

Comment: We usually iterate directly over the list items in Python, it generally results in cleaner code than indirect iteration via indices. cmpgamer has answered your question, but I strongly suggest that you work through the official Python tutorial - it's designed for people who can already program (preferably in a language from the C family).

Comment: @Jean-Francois Fabre where is it wrong?

Comment: now that you have edited it, it's not wrong anymore

Answer (score 3):

In Python, if you have an iterable, you would use a For-Each type For loop.

```
for item in someList:
    print(item)
```

To replicate a C++ like For loop, you have to be a bit creative. There are many ways to go about it but here is what I normally show people who aren't used to Python's conventions.

```
for i in range(len(someList)):
    print(someList[i])
```

You can also enumerate each of the indices in an iterable using the `enumerate()` function.

```
for index, item in enumerate(someList):
    print("Index is {}".format(index))
    print(item)
```